# Which kind of technology are used on google docs share

Tags: javascript

I need understand and know about how I can do something. In my project I need create something similar to technology on google docs.

**When I have a share document with other people and he and I are editing in same time and I see the alterations from him.**

I don't know if is called inverse ajax or other type of techology.

Someone can explain to me which kind of development is it.

**--EDIT--**

On trello.com I found the same idea. When someone change a issue o tab in my dashboard I receive this information.

Comment: Question is a bit too generalized without any specific question about what issues you are having. You may have a better time checking another StackExchange site

Comment: Look on google for `Web Socket`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's called Operational Transformation (OT)

This article could be usefull: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_transformation

Taken from the same article:

> The basic idea of OT can be illustrated by using a simple text editing
>   scenario as follows. Given a text document with a string "abc"
>   replicated at two collaborating sites; and two concurrent operations:
>
> ```
> O1 = Insert[0, "x"] (to insert character "x" at position "0")
> O2 = Delete[2, "c"] (to delete the character "c" at position "2")
> ```
>
> generated by two users at collaborating sites 1 and 2, respectively.
>   Suppose the two operations are executed in the order of O1 and O2 (at
>   site 1). After executing O1, the document becomes "xabc". To execute
>   O2 after O1, O2 must be transformed against O1 to become: O2' =
>   Delete[3, "c"], whose positional parameter is incremented by one due
>   to the insertion of one character "x" by O1. Executing O2' on "xabc"
>   deletes the correct character "c" and the document becomes "xab".
>   However, if O2 is executed without transformation, it incorrectly
>   deletes character "b" rather than "c". **The basic idea of OT is to
>   transform (or adjust) the parameters of an editing operation according
>   to the effects of previously executed concurrent operations so that
>   the transformed operation can achieve the correct effect and maintain
>   document consistency**.

And a very cool link implementing this: http://sharejs.org/

Comment: Wow I had no idea how much research has gone into this, and for how long. TIL. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @MBillau You are welcome! Yes, it's a very interesting technology.

Comment: @Matías, thank you. Is this. My application have some things look like a Trello.com

Comment: @Matías, to use sharejs is necessary the server nodejs or I can use my IIS?