# What is the frontend technology of Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, frontend

I would like to study and explore how Google Sheets implements a super fast spreadsheet online. I have tried searching but most results are about web app scripts for Google Docs.

I am not looking to understand Operational Transformation, but the javascript that builds the cells and how it handles the data in them.

Comment: JavaScript, CSS, and HTML? Or are you asking if they use a library/framework? --- Please note that questions asking for frameworks, tools, etc, is off-topic. See [help/on-topic] for more info.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19860519/which-kind-of-technology-are-used-on-google-docs-share

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which kind of technology are used on google docs share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19860519/which-kind-of-technology-are-used-on-google-docs-share)

Comment: @evolutionxbox nope